# How to use put from private part from spec?

Tags: private, ada, put

How to use put from private part from spec? i am unable to use put please help to fix below is my code

p.ads(spec)

```ada
 package p is
   type t is private;
   give_public_acess:constant t;
 private
   type t is range 1..10;
   give_public_acess:Constant t:=9;
 end p;
```

private_acc.adb

```ada
 with ada.Text_IO,ada.Integer_Text_IO;
  with p;
  procedure private_acc is
   package my_type is new ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(p.t);
   v:p.t;
   begin
    v:=p.give_public_acess;
   my_type.put(v); -- How to print every thing? Is it ok just put is not good here. please help me to fix?
   end private_acc;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your type t is private, so there is no way that procedure private_acc can know whether it is an integer, or float, or anything (this is the whole point of private types).

If you want to be able to display them then you need to export a Put method from your package p that other subprograms can call.

So

```ada
package p is
  type t is private;
  procedure Put (Item : T);
...
```

This will probably mean that the package body of P will need to instantiate Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO;
Alternatively you could instantiate it into a private child package of package P which the package body would then perform call throughs to Put.

Edit: package body added...

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO;
package body P is
   package T_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(T);

   procedure Put(Item : T) is
   begin
      T_IO.Put(Item); -- call through.
   end;
end P;
```

Comment: with ada.Integer_Text_IO,ada.Text_IO;
--use ada.Text_IO,ada.Integer_Text_IO;
package body p is
   procedure put(item:t) is
   begin
     put(item); --raised storage_error as exception can u plz show?
   end put;
   end p;
      u mean like this but it is

Comment: Your `put` is calling itself. Eventually one such call raises a storage error, no surprise there. In the body you know it's some kind of integer, so it's safe to cast it ... ` put(Integer(item));`

Comment: Putting more than a tiny fragment of code in a comment Does Not Work.